# Java syntax error on token.... Identifier expected after this token

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am getting Java

> Syntax error on token "callMe", Identifier expected after this token

on below line of my program:

```
c1.callMe();
```

```
class Class2 {
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    c1.callMe();
}

public class Class1 {
    public void callMe() {
        System.out.println("I am called!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
c1.callMe();
```

Must be moved to a method, it can't be at the class definition level, else it makes no sense (when would your code be executed??):

```
public class Class2 {
    public void doSomething() {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        c1.callMe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you write classes correctly in Java :)

```
class Class2 {
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    public void callMe(){
        c1.callMe();
     }
}
public class Class1 {
    public void callMe() {
        System.out.println("I am called!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Main method and re-arrange your code:

```
public class Class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        c1.callMe();
    }
}
class Class1 {
    void callMe(){
    System.out.println("I am called!!");
   }
}
```