# WindowLIstener - Identifier Expected After Token

Tags: java, syntax, windowlistener

I am refactoring my code based on advice from my CodeReview.SE question. 
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126634/button-clicking-ui-for-a-game

**Research:**

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html
   How to write Window Listeners
2. [Java syntax error on token.... Identifier expected after this token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720949/java-syntax-error-on-token-identifier-expected-after-this-token)
   Most other relatable SO questions are similar to this. I'm unable to find a question with this situation.

I know that you have to create a method to call elsewhere. The doSomething code can't just sit in the class level.

**Error:**
I am encountering the error

> Syntax error on token "saveGameOnClose", Identifier expected after this token

within

```
FRAME.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    SaveGameData.saveGameOnClose();
                });
```

of my main class.

**Main Class:**

```
public Game() {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                NewGameMessage.LoadNewGameMessage();

                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); }
                catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(); }

                FRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                FRAME.getContentPane().add(new addComponentsToPane());

                FRAME.setSize(300, 500);
                FRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                FRAME.setVisible(true);
                FRAME.setResizable(false);

                FRAME.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    SaveGameData.saveGameOnClose();
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

**SaveGameData class:**

```
public class SaveGameData {

//  Game.FRAME.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        static void saveGameOnClose(WindowEvent e) {
            BufferedWriter writerOut = null;
            try {
                writerOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("res/saved_game_data.txt"));
                writerOut.write(String.valueOf(Game.biDamageOutput) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.biPoints) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.biNewPoints) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.biSpentPoints) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.biKnifeCount) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.biPistolCount) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.biShotgunCount) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.biRifleCount) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.biRLauncherCount) + "\r\n" + 
                        String.valueOf(Game.intTotalClicks));
                writerOut.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                  System.err.println("Error: " + e1.getMessage());
                }
        };
}
```

**Personal thought to the problem:**

I'm writing the Window Listener incorrectly. But I'm trying to class each notable action, load, save, UI, individually as part of learning more about classes, sustainability, re-usability of my code. Or I just might be missing one brace or bracket.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `SaveGameData.saveGameOnClose(WindowEvent e)` requires a parameter of type `WindowEvent` but you are calling it without any parameters `SaveGameData.saveGameOnClose();` and that too without implementing any listener method

It should be something like this

```
FRAME.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            SaveGameData.saveGameOnClose(e);
     }

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I was close to doing something like this but was confusing myself between it and the class. I kept trying to create the method off of saveGameOnClose() and knew that wasn't right. 
Will accept as answer when timer is done.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Have fun coding :)